# Where can I find the goblin tinkerer?

Tags: terraria

With the 1.1 update, rocket boots are no longer a random drop. Instead they must be purchased from the goblin tinkerer. The wiki isn't very specific about where to find the little bugger, stating that he appears in a cave or the dungeon after defeating a goblin army. Could someone please provide some more specific tips on how to find him?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There aren't really any more specific tips on how to find him because he spawns randomly.

After you've beaten the Goblin Army (after patch 1.1), he has a chance of spawning near you if you're underground (between the rock layer and the Underworld). Just revisit the Dungeon or go cave diving for a bit and you should find him sooner or later.

Also, you should chug a [Hunter Potion](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hunter_Potion) to increase your odds of finding him if he does spawn. It makes him glow in a green light, just like enemies.

Comment: I've read elsewhere that he spawns anywhere in the world. Someone else said that he found the tinkerer in the Dungeon 6 times.

Comment: @jcollum Dungeon and underground aren't mutually exclusive. I know for a fact "anywhere" isn't true, though. Gotta be below the rock layer.

Comment: I've consistently found him in the dungeon, are you sure he doesn't exclusive spawn there?

Comment: @SadlyNot 100%. Didn't find mine there and I looked at the source code for this answer. Maybe he's just easier to find in the dungeon? Lots of open, connected spaces for him to spawn. Who knows, the NPC spawning algorithm is a complete mess.

Comment: Could it be related to the type of blocks used in the dungeon? I recall seeing those blocks in other regions of the world but it's been a long time ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for him in the dungeon with skeletron. (probaly on a new world if its your same world as the one you had before the update). or you can go to the underworld after defeating a goblin army  and finding him there.

Also he has a 1 out of 3 chances of spawning in either the cavern layer in a forest or jungle.