# Can I find a Goblin Tinkerer on a pre-1.1 world?

Tags: terraria

I'm never sure what to do when Terraria updates, make a new world or continue on my old one where I already have my potion/mushroom farms/proper storage. I really want to make some of the things that the Goblin Tinkerer offers, but I'm not sure whether or not he can be found on a world generated before version 1.1.

If I'm on a world that was generated before version 1.1 and a Goblin Invasion occurs, will I be able to find the Goblin Tinkerer somewhere in my underground, or will this only work on post-1.1 worlds?

Comment: I would say if you have never had one before then its possible, but I am just guessing at how the flag to make the tinkerer show up might be done... Only way to figure this out is to play and see I guess.

Comment: I'll see if I can dig up the reference, but I saw somewhere that defeating an invasion before the patch doesn't count for unlocking the Tinkerer… which implies that the Tinkerer *can* be unlocked on pre-1.1 worlds by defeating a new invasion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can. He isn't generated with the world (else nobody would ever find him), but instead [spawns near you underground](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39673/where-can-i-find-the-goblin-tinkerer/39711#39711) for you to rescue, after you've defeated a Goblin Army.

The only catch is that Goblin Armies defeated before patch 1.1 do *not* count, because it's the first version to keep track of that. You'll have to wait for the next invasion, or use a [Goblin Battle Standard](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goblin_Battle_Standard).

Comment: And that's not just speculation. I rescued him on my first world that by now falls just short of venerable. v1.0.0 or 1.0.1, I think it is.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

I just found him today, in my very first world that I created before the 1.1 update.