# How do bound NPCs spawn?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria, there are bound NPCs: the mechanic, the wizard and the goblin tinkerer. They spawn bound underground, you can unbind them by talking to them and they will move into an available house. I've managed to find the first 2 easily, but the goblin tinker keeps eluding me. What are the best places to look? If they spawn and I miss them, will they spawn elsewhere, or will I need to scour the entire map again to find the spot where they spawned first?

Comment: Did you beat the goblin army?

Comment: @SovietOnion yes, and I've already found the tinkerer tied up in an underground jungle. I probably missed the bugger a dozen times because his appearance doesn't contrast with the background as much as the other's.

Comment: I found the Goblin Tinkerer right inside my Hellevator...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bound NPCs spawn just like monsters: They appear in a radius around you, off-screen, and will despawn at some point.

If they are killed or despawn by themselves before you get to them, they will eventually spawn around you again.

All of them will only spawn while you are underground. Additionally:

- The Wizard only spawns in hard mode.
- The Mechanic only spawns in the Dungeon.
- The Goblin Tinkerer only spawns after you've fended off a goblin invasion.

The Goblin Tinkerer has pretty much no preferred hangouts. See [this answer I gave here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39673/where-can-i-find-the-goblin-tinkerer/39711#39711); basically, the most effective way to find him is to wander around aimlessly underground while chugging [Hunter Potions](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Hunter_Potion) (it reveals bound NPCs just like monsters).

Playing fullscreen at native resolution also helps.

Comment: Quick question about the "if they are killed" statement. The stylist is in Spider Nests, and I found her... And the spiders killed her before I even got to unbind her. So she should still respawn at some point, correct?

Comment: @LLF, that seems like it could be its own question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the goblin tinkerer spawns more often in the jungle and the dungeon. You have to beat at least one goblin army first. For more info look [here](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Goblin_Tinkerer)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Arqade! Terraria actually has an official wiki, which is generally more accurate. I'd suggest that instead of wikia: http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Goblin_Tinkerer .

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/80128/106901):

There is also the Stylist which only spawns in a Spider's Nest.

Not technically bound but there is also the Tax Collector which only spawns in the underworld, attack him with purification powder to get the NPC.

Answer (score -2):

I tend to find that if you are in the dungeon, you should set up a farm for bones (And the ever-so-elusive nazar) The farm should involve the Player going up or down for, at minimum, 47 blocks (47 is the number of blocks from the player a mob will spawn on the vertical axis). Doing this, when you go to kill the mobs, the npc will have a chance to spawn.

Comment: I don't think 'make a farm' is an useful answer to 'how do I find NPCs'